# A recursively defined binary predicate for outcome $1$ in the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

So I have this problem which I can't seem to prove.

> Define the predicate $RP(a,b)$ for positive naturals $a$ and $b$ as follows.   $RP(a,b)$ is defined to be true if and only if one of the following is true:
>
> - $a = 1$;
> - $b = 1$;
> - $a > b$ and $RP(a-b,b)$;
> - $a < b$ and $RP(a, b-a)$.
>
>   1. Prove that $RP(a,b)$ is true if and only if the Euclidean algorithm returns $1$ on inputs $a$ and $b$.

I really do not even know where to begin with this. I know that because the Euclidean algorithm returns a $1$ for both $a$ and $b$ then they are relatively prime. I do not know where to go from here. Any help is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt so far reduces the claim to be proved to:

$$RP(a,b) \iff \gcd(a,b) = 1$$

We can show this by total induction on $a + b$.

- The base case is $2$, for $a,b \ge 1$. If $a+b=2$, $a = b =1$. Hence, $RP(a,b)$; but also $\gcd(a,b)=1$. That is, $RP(a,b) \iff \gcd(a,b) = 1$.
- Suppose that $a+b=n$, and if $a'+b' < n$, then: $$RP(a',b')\iff \gcd(a',b')=1$$
  Using these assumptions, we need to prove:
  \begin{align}RP(a,b) &\implies \gcd(a,b)=1 \\\gcd(a,b)=1 &\implies RP(a,b)\end{align}
  Can you do this?